# Cycle names thru list

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, edgar

I have 3 simple lines of code which pull S-1 filings from the SEC's "Edgar" database and put them into a folder I specify. This uses the "sec Edgar downloader." It works great, but I have to do this for about 1400 companies.

I have the list of tickers in a separate excel spreadsheet. I assume that there must be a way to do this recursively so that it automatically looks up all the tickers I have.

See, the code I already have. I used Starbucks (it's stock ticker "SBUX") as the example company. I don't want to have to redo these 3 lines 1,400 times and manually input all the different tickers.

```
import sec_edgar_downloader
downloader = sec_edgar_downloader.Downloader(r"C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Outputs")
downloader.get_s1_filing_for_ticker("SBUX")
```

I expect a code that would look like this:

```
import sec_edgar_downloader
downloader = sec_edgar_downloader.Downloader(r"C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Outputs")
downloader.get_s1_filing_for_ticker(special.code.to.pull.from.list)
```

Or possibly use some kind of for-loop structure, etc.

Thanks in advance for all the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to done! :-)

```
import sec_edgar_downloader
downloader = sec_edgar_downloader.Downloader(r"C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Outputs")

for ticker in ticker_list:
     downloader.get_s1_filing_for_ticker(ticker)
```

Here ticker list will look like this:

```
ticker_list = ["SBUX","SBAX", "UBIX","TAXA" ]
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how to set up ticker list?

Comment: if you want code to extract a column from a spreadsheet it probably easiest to just use pandas.

Comment: Nice!! This is great! Thanks so much!